# How to make client not disconnect when server response takes a long time

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, http

I have a Java backend with REST-API and an Angularjs frontend. Users can use the frontend to request information from the backend. When this happens, the backend generates a file on the fly and sends it to the frontend. So far so good.

The problem occurs when users request large amounts of information. This makes generating the file take so long that the frontend times out and aborts the connection.

Is there a way to reassure the client that a response is actually going to come, or increase the timeout limit for this one endpoint only? Alternatively, is there a way for the server to send two responses, one immediately after receiving the request and one after the file is generated?

The API endpoint looks like this:

```
@Path("download")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response download() {

    StreamingOutput stream = //stream containing file

    return Response.ok(stream)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"download.xlsx\"")
        .build();
}
```

The frontend makes the request by doing `window.open(download url, '_blank', '')` (the content of the file depends on previous input from the user).

Comment: could you buffer and stream the file content instead of generating it? and doing an ajax request from front end to display information as they're recieved?

Comment: For other formats, e.g. CSV, I'm streaming the file as it's being generated, so that's no problem. But I don't know how to do that for Excel, as I'm using a framework (apache poi) to generate the file.

Comment: not sure how that API works, but you could do an ajax to check your service if file is generated, then display the results once it's done, and display a loader if it isn't